# Reading a line backwards

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using regular expression to count the total spaces in a line (first occurrence).
    match(/^\s*/)[0].length;

However this reads it from the start to end, How can I read it from end to start.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that a regex is the best way to count spaces. Surely a simple loop would be easier to understand and more maintainable?

Comment: ... the amount of questions on SO mis-applying regex is mind-boggling.

Comment: Maybe we could get the SO developers to write a regex that catches bad regex posts.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
function reverse(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

To use it:

```
var str = 'Hello World';
alert(reverse(str));
```

How it works, we split the string by an empty character to turn it into an array, then we reverse the order of the array, then we join it all back together, using no character as the glue. So we get alerted `dlroW olleH`

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to find the number of trailing spaces on a line?

```
s.match(/\s*$/)[0].length;
```

Or last spaces found, even if there's something else trailing:

```
s.match(/(\s*)[^\s]*$/)[1].length
```

Answer (score 1):

do you just want to know how many chars there is before the space? If so, does this not suit your needs.

```
var str = 'The quick brown fox jumps';

var first = str.indexOf(' ');
var last = str.lastIndexOf(' ');

alert('first space is at: ' + first + ' and last space is at: ' + last);
```

Comment: Something like this "Hello World<4 spaces>Test" would return '4' spaces,

Comment: @Jimmy in that case wombleton's second regex would return the right value

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using regular expression to count the total spaces in a line

Then why do you care about which way it counts? "aaa" contains 3 a's whether I start from the first or last one. 3 is still 3...